# For what value of k are these 3 vectors linearly dependent

Tags: matlab

So I have these three vectors:

[image]

And I have to find out for what value of k these three vectors are **linearly dependent**. I have tried using **rref** and **linsolve** with syms for this but that did not work out. I'm relatively new to MatLab and matrices so please keep that in mind.

I know in order to check if vectors are linearly dependent that c1...cn have to be **non-zero**.

I also want to know how you can use variables in general when solving these types of equations in MatLab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A set of vectors (at least if you have `n` vectors in `n` dimensions) is linearly dependent if the matrix constructed from them is singular, i.e. if its determinant is 0. If you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, you can construct a symbolic matrix:

```
syms k;
M = [1 k 0; -1 1 2; 0 0 3];
det(M)
```

This will tell you that `det(M)==3*k+3`, which you can solve by hand. But generally, you can ask matlab to solve it:

```
solve(det(M)==0,k);
```

which will tell you the answer is `-1`. So unless `k==-1`, these vectors are linearly independent (i.e. they comprise a basis of the Euclidean space `R^3`).

**Update:** If you *don't* have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, you could still try to find a numerical solution. First define a function

```
detfun=@(k) det([1 k 0; -1 1 2; 0 0 3]);
```

that for any value of `k` will give you the determinant of your matrix, for instance `detfun(3)` gives 12. Then you can use `fsolve` to find a numerical solution to the equation `detfun(k)==0`, by calling

```
 fsolve(detfun,0)
```

in which the second argument, `0`, refers to the starting point of the search performed by `fsolve`. This will tell you that the answer is `k==-1`, but a single call to `fsolve` will only give you a single solution. If your function has multiple roots, you have to play around with the starting points to find more of them. In this case, you can know that your function (i.e. `det(M(k))` is linear in `k`, so it has a unique root.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a clear insight of how MatLab handles things. I can't use solve(det(M)==0,k) however, that just gives me ans=k.

Comment: @werter318, do you have the Symbolic math toolbox? Without that you won't have much luck: matlab was built for numerical problems (read: matrices and vectors), and that's where it thrives.

Comment: @werter318  You can also use a numerical solution: first define a function `detfun=@(k) det([1 k 0; -1 1 2; 0 0 3]);` that will give you the determinant for a given value of `k`, then use it with `fsolve` to get a numerical answer: `fsolve(detfun,0)`. This will solve the equation `detfun(k)==0`, starting from `k=0`. However, it will always only find a single solution.

Comment: I don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox. I have an academic version of MatLab which probably doesn't have that. It would come in handy though I think, so is there any way I can get it?

Comment: @werter318, you should probably ask Mathworks;) But if you need to solve symbolic problems, matlab might not be the best solution. Wolfram Mathematica, while a monster of a swiss-army knife, is much more versed in solving symbolic problems (but makes solving numerical problems as fun as a smallpox pandemic).